# Can Islamic beliefs be accommodated into certain sect of Hinduism?

Tags: vedas, other-religions, sects, islam

Islam is a strict monotheist faith like Judaism and Sikhism, and we also find support of [monotheism in the Vedas](http://www.islamandhinduism.com/ih/articles%20of%20faith.html) to the extent [that there are some sects which prohibit idol worship among the Hindus](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/630/which-hindu-sects-prohibit-idol-worship).
The [fundamental core Islamic beliefs](http://www.islamreligion.com/category/50/) like:

1. Only one God (i.e. Allah)
2. Prophet as messenger of God
3. Afterlife system with heaven/hell
4. Angels & virgins
5. Revealed books (i.e. Quran)
6. Divine predestination

Can Islam be accommodated in Hinduism such that Islam can be seen as a non conflicting sect within Hinduism?

Comment: Can Islam concepts be accepted by Hindus? Why not. While not everyone subscribes to this belief, many great saints in the recent 'multi-religious-strife-struck-world' have emphasized that 'All religions are true, all are but different paths to the One God'. Examples of such saints are Sri Ramakrishna , Saint Kabir Das, Paramahansa Yogananda, Sri Sai Baba (Shirdi, Sathya Sai) who also emphasize on unity of religions. All religions speak the same truth, while their interpretations vary according to different faith! Not all subscribe to this belief, it must be clarificated :)!

Comment: Although I can't remember where, I am quite sure that in the Bagavat Gita it specifically says that all other religions are equal paths to the same God. While there may be some differences in theology (they wouldn't be two separate religions if there weren't) there is no reason to think that the two religions are mutually exclusive. As far as more specific beliefs go, you may have to consult Hindu scriptures to clarify.

Comment: I think rather than believing in anything taught to you as god and becoming religious become Spiritual and experience god himself by following path of yoga and attain atmagyan.

Comment: I think Islamic doctrine teaches ethical conduct that directly opposes those taught by Dharmic religions (eg. Hinduism).

Comment: I can answer this question with references from teachings of Swami Rama and biographies of great Swamis. But answer says how Islam is misinterpreted and answer may become controversial. All Religions are true and they lead to one God.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Islam as a whole can be very easily accommodated as a sect within Hinduism very much like how Sikhism, Buddhism, Jainism etc have been recognised as Hindu by Indian legal system.

Islam is a religion that is often seen as being at odds with Hinduism. However, there are many similarities between the two religions, and there is a strong case to be made for making Islam a sub-sect within Hinduism as a welcome addition and advancement of Hindu tradition.
One of the main similarities between Islam and Hinduism is their belief in monotheism advocated by Vedas but compromised by later belief systems from Puranas. Both religions believe in one supreme God, and they both have a strong emphasis on prayer and meditation. Additionally, both religions have a strong sense of community, and they both place a high value on family and family values.

Another similarity between Islam and Hinduism is their belief in soul getting paid back for the karmas.

In fact, Hinduism is already a very diverse religion, and it encompasses a wide range of beliefs and practices. There are Hindu atheists, Hindu agnostics, and Hindu polytheists. There are even Hindu sects that worship Jesus Christ or Allah.
Given the diversity and tolerance of Hinduism, it makes sense to make Islam a sub-sect within Hinduism. This would allow Muslims to maintain their own unique beliefs and practices, while also being part of a larger and more diverse religious community.

There are many benefits to making Islam a sub-sect within Hinduism. One benefit is that it would promote interfaith understanding and cooperation. It would also help to reduce religious intolerance and discrimination. Additionally, it would help to create a more united and harmonious society.

Of course, there are also some challenges to making Islam a sub-sect within Hinduism. The only  major challenge is that there is a history of conflict and violence between Hindus and Muslims. However, making it as sub sect  will actually foster compassion among each other and eliminate the historical biases and unite both.

Overall, there is a strong case to be made for making Islam a sub-sect within Hinduism. This would be a positive step for both religions, and it would help to create a more united and harmonious society.

**How Even Charvaka Which Is Atheist Philosophy Finds Acceptance In Hinduism**

Charvaka is an ancient Indian philosophy that is considered to be the oldest materialist and atheist philosophy in the world. Charvakas believe that there is no soul, no afterlife, and no God. They believe that the only thing that is real is the physical world, and that the goal of life is to enjoy oneself.
Charvaka is a very different philosophy from Hinduism, which is a deeply religious tradition. However, Charvaka is still accepted within Hinduism. This is because Hinduism is a very diverse religion, and it encompasses a wide range of beliefs and practices.
The acceptance of Charvaka within Hinduism shows that Hinduism is a very tolerant and inclusive religion. It is a religion that is open to different beliefs and practices, and it is a religion that accepts people from all walks of life.

**Conclusion**

There is a strong case to be made for making Islam a sub-sect within Hinduism. This would be a positive step for both religions, and it would help to create a more united and harmonious society.
Hinduism is a diverse religion that has assimilated many different beliefs and practices over the centuries. It is a religion that is based on the principle of tolerance and acceptance. Hinduism has a long history of accepting and incorporating different cultures and religions.
It would also allow Muslims to practice their religion freely while also being a part of a larger religious community.

Answer (score 8):

The keynote to Hinduism is 'Ekam Sat Vipra Bahudha Vadanti - That which exists is One, men call it by various names'. All religions are true. Ramakrishna Parmahamsa said All clocks tell time, but all show a different time and none are exactly right. So are all religions.

Who are we to argue as to what is true or not true in a particular religion? Have you seen God? Has He told you directly? Religions are maps only, they are not God. See God then you can ask Him directly what is true and not true.

It says in the Atharva Veda 'Ekarh Jyotir Bahudha Bibhati - The One Light appears in diverse forms'

And in the Mahimnah Stotra -'As the different streams having their sources in different places all minngle their waters in the sea, so, O Lord, the different paths which men take through different tendencies, various though they appear, crooked or straight, all lead to Thee.'

All religions belong to God, God does not belong to any religions.

Swami Vivekananda has said that he accepts all religious beliefs, the only belief he does not accept is when a person says my religion alone is true, all other religions are false.

Comment: Islam in itself literally means submission to God alone.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda, what do you think about katha upanishad 2.2.13 nityo nityānāṁ cetanaś cetanānām
eko bahūnāṁ yo vidadhāti kāmān
tam ātma-sthaṁ ye ’nupaśyanti dhīrās
teṣāṁ śāntiḥ śāśvatī netareṣām ? It says There are many eternals and one eternal provides for all the eternals.

Comment: Katha U 2.2.13 - "There is One who is the eternal Reality among non-eternal objects, the one conscious Entity among conscious objects, and who, though non-dual fulfills the desire of many. Eternal peace belongs to the wise, who perceive Him within themselves--not to others." What is your question?

Comment: Another translation - "Eternal peace is for those--and not for others--who are discriminating and who realize in their hearts Him who--being the eternal among the ephemeral, the consciousness among the conscious--alone dispenses the desired objects to many."

Answer (score 2):

Why should they?

Sanatana Dharma does not need to adopt any other religion's doctrines. It is complete in itself. What makes you think Sanatana Dharma does not have concepts you list?

1. Belief in one God  - What do you think our Vedas propound? It is just one Brahma Padartham.
2. Belief in Prophets - We don't need prophets. However, Sanatana Dharma's foundation is upheld and strengthened by Rishis and sages who have, through tapas, envisioned the ultimate truth (this is called darshana) and have passed on the ultimate truth and keep doing so even now.
3. Belief in Hereafter  - Err.. why do you think this is missing in Sanatana Dharma? We are continuously extolled to practise dharma in the pursuit of punya and eventually moksha.
4. Belief in angels - We have 33 types of devtas - all superior to angels.
5. Belief in revealed books  - Vedas and mantras are always revealed to a tapasa.
6. Belief in divine predestination  - Read Bhagavad Gita.

We don't need any new reformers for Sanatana Dharma . It is enough if we can even partially understand rishi hrudayam and practise dharma as outlined by the rishis.

Islam is not and need not be adopted as a sub-religion of Hinduism.

Comment: I think the tone of the original Qn is different. In my understanding it's like: "*SanAtana Dharma* is very vast and contains lots of sects, doctorines & philosophies. Islam is a simple and singular philosophy. Which sect of *SanAtana Dharma* can be comparable to the philosophies of Islam. For example, Parasi's Zoroastrianism can be related to certain philosophy of Hinduism, who pray to the *Agni devatA*." Another analogy can be -- Apple (Islam) fits into the Samsung's (Hinduism) PC & phone making business among vast array of other businesses.

Comment: @iammilind Doesn't matter. It is not a question worth exploring either from a philosophical pov or SE pov. It is especially not worthy because it perpetrates the notion that hinduism is a dumping bag of all beliefs and does not have its own identity. It is also a tool that conversionists are using to convert hindus into their religions. Therefore It is not worthy for sociopolitical reasons also.

Comment: @iammilind I have updated this as an answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56575/225

Answer (score -1):

Short Answer : **NO**

Islamic beliefs are broadly :

1. Islam is only true religion and Muhammad was final prophet
2. Permanent heaven (woman, wine etc) and hellfire
3. Jihad to expand Islam against infidels
4. Monotheism
5. Final goal is heaven
6. Only formless God to be " worshipped "
7. Judgemental God which gives fear and greed for hell and heaven
8. Creator is outside of its creation

Vedanta beliefs :

1. All ways are valid to "reach" divine. No need to belief in any prophet or anything. Guru is needed but one has to work Tapas for himself
2. Monism
3. No permanent heaven or hell
4. Non expansionist
5. Final Goal is Moksha or Nirvana
6. All forms are his, worship whatever pleases
7. No fear nor greed. Rise above these
8. Creator is embedded in every atom

Above two cannot be reconciled