# how hindusim surviveed even though it was under external occupation

Tags: other-religions, christianity, islam, conversion

India was ruled by Islamic invaders and christian west.

How come hinduism survives and continues to flourish ?

the same happened in africa, america and australia. ony christianity and Islam survives there.

In most places pagan religions are all died out except india.

What makes hinduism stand out and flourise ?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11472)

Comment: Hinduism did not "survive and flourish" it was altered throughout history.