# How geographical birth is influenced by karma?

Tags: mahabharata, karma, dharma-shastras, smriti, birth

Thank you to the answerers to another question which I will link below. I want to point out that I do not believe in original sin but I believe in karma.

[What attributes of Hinduism allowed it to survive centuries of proselytisation by Muslims and Christians?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11472/22667)

My answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44211/22667

So if I was born inside a dumb Adharmik place like sadly it is in my case and my sadness come from the non-accepting the identities of this place,because luckily I understand things as they are,  could it be that in my previous life maybe I violated another place?

In the end: why I was born in Europe and in a christian country, if myself spontaneously approach to Sanatan Dharma so well and consider that this should be my identity through life styles and rituals such those belonging to any Indian Hindu communities and also I feel that I should have always followed the 4 purushartas and I feel like I am in delay and out of my original place and that my biological family is not my family, since birth of this body? I feel that this is not my place since ever on this life. Why? Help.

In Europe we have Hindu Temples but India is Hindu source. Or I hope so.

**Requirements** needed in order **to answer well** and help **this question** to be well answered:

**This question will be completely satisfied by adding experiencial examples,I mean: Being a Hindu believer or a new changed ex- Abrahmic -that is those people who deeply did rejected the Maya illusion of any Abrahmic Faiths- In both cases the answers will be useful. Can be answered also by Puranas or Shastras, Ramayana and Mahabharat, or Yog explanation by who truly can master them, so in this case Sanaatani. And also Yogini can be able to answer too, accordingly to their knowledge and also the people who asked themselves the same. The Author of the question does not accept any form of Abrahmic explanation. Excuse me but so it is in my case. Thanks again for understanding me.**

---

Stack Exchange need to be clear when say "do not meet prerequisites".

Comment: your current birth is determined by your actions in previous lives, just as your next birth is determined by actions in the current. If a rich man commits a crime, he goes to jail, but he still can buy himself some comforts due to his past wealth. Similarly, those Sanatanis who slip a little and get birth in other countries/religions, will still be drawn towards Sanatan dharm due to their past samskara. If you really want to know what you were in your past birth, you have to do a specific arduous penance for 12 years - You can read Vivekananda's works to find out what it is (he did it btw).

Comment: @ram Jay Sree Ram tell me the book and describe me more things please.

Comment: And thank you @ram until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can only be answered by Ishvara.

> The fruit of action is from Him, this being the logical position

**Brahma Sutra III.ii.38**

Since Ishvara distributes the fruits of Karma only He can give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

The karma performed by us has the capacity to determine many things about our next life. Out karma determines where our soul migrates to... A animal body or another human body, or attain higher celestial abodes. The nature of karma plays a important role in that. The geographical location is also determined by karma and desire of the lord.

If we have caused pain to someone, we have to face the consequences of it equally maybe this life or other. If ur karmas are good and such that ur close to attaining advanced spirituality and going back to the spiritual world, then the lord may give us a chance to do it wherever he feels we may get the opportunity easily but it's up to us to utilise it or leave it.

**Very good answer but: Lacking of more experiencial examples, Puranas or Shastras or Yog explanation. Can be improved **

Comment: Very good answer but: Lacking of more experiencial examples, Puranas or Shastras or Yog explanation. Can be improved @Religious Believers. Furthermore I follow Dharma so "Lord" here is too aspecific and generic. Thanks to understanding me and thanks for your still useful answer.